# Is it possible to get current experiment name in kubeflow pipeline?

Tags: kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

When in pipeline code I can use macros like
`{{workflow.annotations.pipelines.kubeflow.org/run_name}}` or  `{{workflow.name}}` to get those values, and potentially use them in some context, eg. passing to some component.

What I'd like to do is get current experiment name, that the run is assigned to. I'd like to pass it on to components for logging purposes.

Is this property exposed?